# How to export DXF lines and polylines into one shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line, export, dxf

I imported a DXF file into QGIS and now after editing it, I wish to save different parts of it as a shapefile. When I go to save the layers by highlighting the ones I want and pressing right click > Export > Save as and select shapefile etc. it only saves either the polylines or the lines layer into the shapefile, when I want both.

How could I go about solving this issue?

Project Files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vOr-572lbqs0Xok34tXjnTEwUfJbb23e/view?usp=sharing

Under Important bits, I wish to convert each of the groups "Rakennus_talousrakennus", "Rakennus_valmis" etc. into 3 seperate shapefiles.

Comment: Are you asking how to [`merge`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?highlight=merge#merge-vector-layers) vector-layers of the same type?

Comment: Not particularly, although I feel that might be the first step to solving this issue. But would lines and polylines even be considered to be of the same type?

Comment: I suggest you either provide your data, or try yourself.

Comment: "Polyline", in the shapefile specification, refers to a linear feature, but if you're asking how to get two different geometry classes (lines and polygons) into a shapefile, you can't: Only one geometry class, plus Nil shapes (zero vertices) is permitted in a shapefile.

Comment: I've now provided the provided the project files. And no I don't think I'm asking how to get two different geometry classes into one, unless polylines and lines are considered to be fully seperate geometry types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to merge the polyline and line layers with the "merge layers" tool under SAGA first. Using that tool, I was automatically able to create shapefiles from my DXF data.